# Decompile jar file from apk, edit java code single variable, and recompile into class and into jar

Tags: java, android, class, apk

There is an old android apk file which is no longer supported by the manufacturer.

I figured out what could be wrong it is because it is calling a method from java:

In one of the java files (viewed after dex2jar and viewing with jd-gui)

**import com.htc.buletoothconfirm;**

All I want to do is to **change that to**

**import com.htc.bluetoothconfirm;**

Then **recompile** it into a **.class file**.
Then **reinsert** that **.class file into a .jar** file.
Then I will **rebuild** the **.apk** file.

The thing is I can't change anything with jd-gui.

If I try to compile a single .java file with javac, it will give me import errors (there are a lot of imports in the file).

I have tried [using jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) to decompile the class file, and this is what I'm working with.

Although it gave a lot of "cannot fully decompile" errors.

What I think I want to do is just copy & paste the entire java file content from jd-gui into notepad, save it as .java, then compile it into .class, and reinsert it into the .jar file.

But its easier said than done. I don't know how to compile this new .java file into a .class file, because of all the imports. (eg. where do I get import android.content.intent; etc? and do i really need to keep the directory structures and so on?)

Is there an easier way? I am just trying to change a single line. All the rest can be kept the same.

Comment: Did you try it with Winrar and cavaj ?apk file is just a zipped file

Comment: I'm not sure why you are answring this way. I have already decompiled it. I already have the jar file, which in turn I have extracted the class files. Then I already can read the .java files. I have created a new .java file and I want to convert this new java file version into .class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decompile apk file with some tools like [ASM-Android](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm/), or [Dedexer](https://github.com/sciruela/ReadableDex). If you want to generate a class, you could generate on-device using sdcard and then create a dex. file and its corresponding .jar. I used [BCEL and ASM](https://github.com/sciruela/android) to generate Bytecode on-device.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I think what I need is the BCEL and ASM, am I right in assuming that I can generate a .class file from a .java code, on-device with this tool?

Unfortunately, I don't understand what to do to generate the .class file. I now have my .java file on my SDcard. I have the sciruela-android file from https://github.com/sciruela/android on the same folder on the SDcard. What do I do?

Comment: You need to use ASM and BCEL libraries. Then, you should write a new class with the correct directories into SD Card. The last step is to add this class to a dex file and finally to pack in a jar to load dynamically. In my example, I have created this class from scratch following the before steps.

Comment: OK, I have already understood adding the class to a dex file and to pack in a jar. My only problem at the moment is to use ASM and BCEL. The tutorials online seem a bit over my head. I don't have the source codes for import android.content.intent, etc, so I think I have to use ASM to generate classes on the fly without source code, right? THis is my first time hearing about ASM. After searching around for 15 mins I still have no clue how to use ASM.

Comment: Dex files aren't containers like jar? Because my only experience iwth dex files is dex2jar and jar2dex, =p should it be more than that?

One last thing though, if I change import classA;  to import classB; in the .java code, that means I won't be able to use bytecode or asm right? Because during the compilation of the original class classA is included in the new compiled .class file, while the classB class isn't included? So I have to recompile the whole thing anyway? Where do I get the com.htc.* class .java codes then in this case?